# RxJava: Observable and default thread

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have the following code:

```
Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(@NonNull final ObservableEmitter<String> s) throws Exception {
                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        s.onNext("1");
                        s.onComplete();
                    }
                });
                thread.setName("background-thread-1");
                thread.start();
            }
        }).map(new Function<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(@NonNull String s) throws Exception {
                String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                logger.logDebug("map: thread=" + threadName);
                return "map-" + s;
            }
        }).subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {}

            @Override
            public void onNext(String s) {
                String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                logger.logDebug("onNext: thread=" + threadName + ", value=" + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {}

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                logger.logDebug("onComplete: thread=" + threadName);
            }
        });
```

And here's the output:

```
map: thread=background-thread-1 
onNext: thread=background-thread-1, value=map-1 
onComplete: thread=background-thread-1
```

Important detail: I'm calling the `subscribe` method from another thread (`main` thread in Android).

So looks like `Observable` class is synchronous and by default and it performs everything (operators like `map` + notifying subscribers) on the same thread which emits events (`s.onNext`), right? I wonder... is it intended behaviour or I just misunderstood something? Actually I was expecting that at least `onNext` and `onComplete` callbacks will be called on the caller's thread, not on the one emitting events. Do I understand correctly that in this particular case actual caller's thread doesn't matter? At least when events are generated asynchronously.

Another concern - what if I receive some Observable as a parameter from some external source (i.e. I don't generate it on my own)... there is no way for me as its user to check if whether it is synchronous or asynchronous and I just have to explicitly specify where I want to receive callbacks via `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` methods, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

RxJava is unopinionated about concurrency. It will produce values on the subscribing thread if you do not use any other mechanisem like observeOn/ subscribeOn. Please don't use low-level constructs like Thread in operators, you could break the contract.

Due to the use of Thread, the onNext will be called from the calling Thread ('background-thread-1'). The subscription happens on the calling (UI-Thread). Every operator down the chain will be called from 'background-thread-1'-calling-Thread. The subscription onNext will also be called from 'background-thread-1'.

If you want to produce values not on the calling thread use: subscribeOn. If you want to switch the thread back to main use observeOn somewhere in the chain. Most likely before subscribing to it.

Example:

```
Observable.just(1,2,3) // creation of observable happens on Computational-Threads
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()) // subscribeOn happens only once in chain. Nearest to source wins
            .map(integer -> integer) // map happens on Computational-Threads
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // Will switch every onNext to Main-Thread
            .subscribe(integer -> {
                // called from mainThread
            });
```

Here is a good explanitation.
http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.de/2016/02/rxjava-understanding-observeon-and.html