# In RxJava, is emitting event by observable multi-threaded?

Tags: java, rx-java

Is RxJava muti-threaded behind the scene, say if an observable below has emitted the event hello, does it do so by creating a new thread ?

Observable observable = Observable.just("Hello");

And if it is multi-threaded, is there any limit on JVM about the maximum number of new threads it can create, and hence the use of Observable may also be limited?

Comment: Answering your other question: there's no limit on the number of threads except by hardware (i.e. not enough memory available to create the thread). To avoid these kinds of situations most frameworks use thread pools instead of creating a thread for each task.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43436640/rxjava-observable-and-default-thread/43437129#43437129 regarding concurrency in RxJava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, nothing in RxJava is multi-threaded. Multi-threading can easily be introduced, however, by using [Schedulers](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#schedulers). For example, if you did this:

```java
Observable.just("Hello")
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
  .subscribe(i -> System.out.println(i +  " " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

You'd see the `println` call happens on a Thread provided by the computation scheduler. Without the `subscribeOn` call, you'd see it run in your main thread.

RxJava provides  several types of Schedulers, which each have different properties. There's the I/O scheduler, which will start by creating a new thread for each request, but will re-use previously created threads once they are free. There's a computation scheduler (which I used above), which operates with a fix-size pool of threads, etc. You can also write your own, if none of the provided ones meet your needs.

I would highly recommend reading documentation on this topic, since RxJava's approach to concurrency is purposely a bit different from what you're probably used to.

Comment: If RxJava is generally not using multi-thread, then how does it achieve concurrency and asynchronous ? I once thought for concurrency it needs to be multi-threaded.

Comment: @sea People that need concurrency with RxJava generally *are* using multiple threads, by using `Schedulers`. It is possible to get concurrency in other ways, like via non-blocking I/O, which can also be leveraged with RxJava.

Comment: Just for completion: NIO is using a threadpool under the hood for completion handlers. I do not know, whether there are implementations for epoll, io_uring yet and whether they use a threadpool or not.